# Cannot consume webservice in javaee

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wildfly

I created webservice which looks like this:

```
@WebService
public class DefaultHolidayCalculatorWS {

@Inject
private HolidayCalculator holidayCalculator;

public Long getDaysTillHoliday() {
    return holidayCalculator.getDaysToHoliday();
}}
```

I deployed this as war on the wildfly. Service was created successfully. Then i created my second application (also .war) which contains:

```
@WebService
public interface HolidayCalculatorWS {
    Long getDaysTillHoliday();
}
```

And servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/soaptest")
public class SOAPTest extends HttpServlet {

@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8082/HolidayCalcWS/DefaultHolidayCalculatorWS?wsdl" )
private HolidayCalculatorWS holidayCalculatorWS;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(holidayCalculatorWS.getDaysTillHoliday());
}
```

}

Deploy this as separate .war on the same wildfly server. When i called http get `.../soaptest` i got error message:'

> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service
>   named null in wsdl
>   http://localhost:8082/HolidayCalcWS/DefaultHolidayCalculatorWS?wsdl
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:173)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:129)    at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.(ProviderImpl.java:572)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:290)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:63)     at
>   javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:710)     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.serviceref.CXFServiceObjectFactoryJAXWS.instantiateService(CXFServiceObjectFactoryJAXWS.java:256)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.serviceref.CXFServiceObjectFactoryJAXWS.getObjectInstance(CXFServiceObjectFactoryJAXWS.java:86)
>     ... 68 more

What is the reason of this problem?

EDIT:

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.app/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="DefaultHolidayCalculatorWSService" targetNamespace="http://ws.app/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://ws.app/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.app/" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="getDaysTillHoliday" type="tns:getDaysTillHoliday"/>
    <xs:element name="getDaysTillHolidayResponse" type="tns:getDaysTillHolidayResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="getDaysTillHoliday">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getDaysTillHolidayResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="daysTillHoliday" type="xs:long"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getDaysTillHolidayResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getDaysTillHolidayResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDaysTillHoliday">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getDaysTillHoliday" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="HolidayCalculatorWS">
    <wsdl:operation name="getDaysTillHoliday">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getDaysTillHoliday" name="getDaysTillHoliday"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getDaysTillHolidayResponse" name="getDaysTillHolidayResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="DefaultHolidayCalculatorWSServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:HolidayCalculatorWS">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDaysTillHoliday">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input name="getDaysTillHoliday">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDaysTillHolidayResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="DefaultHolidayCalculatorWSService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:DefaultHolidayCalculatorWSServiceSoapBinding" name="DefaultHolidayCalculatorWSPort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8082/HolidayCalcWS/DefaultHolidayCalculatorWS"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you share with us your WSDL?

Comment: edited question